# Side by side horizontal input range and vertical input range

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I want to put side-by-side this two input range:

```
<input type="range" class="meter" value="50" min="30" max="80">                                 
<input type="range" class="sensitivity" value="3" orient="vertical" style="-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;"/>
```

I've tried with `display:inline-block` but didn't work.
How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kb5nqmox/)

Its working with `display : inline-block`

```
input{
  width: x|unit /* as per your design */
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle /* vertical alignment if u require -- top | bottom | middle | baseline */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a table?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="range" class="meter" value="50" min="30" max="80"></td>
<td><input type="range" class="sensitivity" value="3" orient="vertical" style="-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

By the way, javascript tag is not suitable for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Make their `widths` 50% (or less if you want a `margin`), and add `float: left`

```css
input {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
  }
```

```html
<input type="range" class="meter" value="50" min="30" max="80">                                 
<input type="range" class="sensitivity" value="3" orient="vertical" style="-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;"/>
```

**EDIT** - If you need extra content alongside these inputs, you can wrap them in a parent div, and give that a fixed width if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

By default input are inline. 
If your two inputs are not side-by-side, it could be due to a container width. 
If parent width is less than two inline, the seconds go on a new line.